# VBA Macro is running extremely slowly

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have this Macro, and finally got it figured out, but it is running very slowly, and would take about 3 days to get through my one sheet of 800 000 lines, and I have 100 sheets. I would appreciate help in this regard.

```
Sub Calculate_Sheet()
   Dim orderSh As Worksheet
   Dim wiroSh As Worksheet
   Dim lastRow As Long, r As Long
   Dim pctComp As Double

 With ThisWorkbook
  'calculator
  Set orderSh = .Sheets("ORDER")
  'price list
  Set wiroSh = .Sheets("WiroA3C100gsmI100gsm20-22pp ")
End With

lastRow = wiroSh.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For r = 2 To lastRow
pctComp = (r / 800000) * 100
Application.StatusBar = "Progress..." & " " & pctComp & " " & "% Complete"

  'copy from price list to calculator
  orderSh.Range("f4") = wiroSh.Range("c" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f5") = wiroSh.Range("d" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f6") = wiroSh.Range("e" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f7") = wiroSh.Range("f" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f8") = wiroSh.Range("g" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f9") = wiroSh.Range("h" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f10") = wiroSh.Range("i" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f11") = wiroSh.Range("j" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f12") = wiroSh.Range("k" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f13") = wiroSh.Range("l" & r)

  'copy result
  wiroSh.Range("m" & r).Value = orderSh.Range("F14")
Next r

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason whatsoever to ever turn screen updating off. its a technique used to speed up inefficient code, if your code isnt inefficient you dont need to worry about screen updating.... ever.....

The theory is very simple.. Dont EVER access/use a range in your code unless absolutely necessary....

Instead dump the entire sheets data into an array and work from that, not only is it fast.... i mean super fast, you can repopulate an entire sheet (that is 32000 columns and 1 million rows) immediately using an array......

and you use the exact same logic to work with the array as you would with a range so you really have no excuse..

```
Dim Arr as variant
Arr = Sheet1.Range("A1:Z100")
```

now instead of Sheet1.Range("A1").value just use Arr(1,1) to access the value

and updating the sheet with the array is just as easy

```
Sheet1.Range("A1:Z100").value = arr
```

its as simple as that, its fast its easy and its the way you SHOULD do it unless its just something small your working on but even then, better to practice the best methods right?

1 thing to note is when you put the array values back to the sheet, you need to use a range that is the same size or larger than the array........ or else it will just fill the range you specify.

Comment: Array is a good idea, but
"if your code isnt inefficient you dont need to worry about screen updating.... ever....."
is absolutely not true, and not only for the sake of speed.

Comment: i never use screen updating to speed up my code....... and if you actually test the theory it has mixed results it doesnt actually always speed up your code.... the only reason i use this is to prevent the screen updating and flickering as code is running, for example adding temporary sheets, deleting them, or anything else that might cause the screen to change during the course of my code running.

Comment: bottom line is if your trying to speed up you code, screen updating is lazy way to do it, and even when iterating through ranges and updating them it might save you 10% of the time it takes to do it when its updating..... the array method requires 1 update............1 single update, there is really no comparison :)

Comment: but the array method has limitations i admit. it only has access to values of the cells, so if you planning on changing object properties this definitely wont work..and you will need to work with the range object

Comment: Yup, that is the point. In this case, the arrays will probably help a lot. But what I insist on, is that you cannot say, that "you don't ever need to worry about screen updating"...

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the array suggestion, I am excited to get it implemented. I have made some change to the code, but I am missing something, as the values are not being put in at all, but the macro runs without bugs...

Answer (score 3):

Also you can try to copy only single range, instead of multiple ranges. I think it can slight increase your performance.

I think, you can replace this

```
  orderSh.Range("f4") = wiroSh.Range("c" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f5") = wiroSh.Range("d" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f6") = wiroSh.Range("e" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f7") = wiroSh.Range("f" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f8") = wiroSh.Range("g" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f9") = wiroSh.Range("h" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f10") = wiroSh.Range("i" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f11") = wiroSh.Range("j" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f12") = wiroSh.Range("k" & r)
  orderSh.Range("f13") = wiroSh.Range("l" & r)
```

with something like this

```
orderSh.Range(orderSh.cells(4,"F"),orderSh.cells(13,"F")) = wiroSh.Range(wiroSh.cells(r,"C"),wiroSh.cells(r,"l"))
```

And as j.kaspar mentioned, usage of `application.screenupdating = false` is great idea, but i would strongly recomend to use something like this on the begining of your macro

```
Dim previousScreenUpdating as boolean
previousScreenUpdating = application.screenUpdating
application.screenUpdating = false
```

and this on the end of your macro

```
application.screenUpdating = previousScreenUpdating
```

Which can help you, when you have nested function in which you setting multiple screenUpdatings...

And also, if you have some formulas on any sheet, make something similar with (on the begining)

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

and this on the end of code

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

And one last, if you have some event listeners, consider using this (same as with screen updating)

```
application.enableEvents
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` on the beginning, and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of the macro.

It will run multiple times faster, when the screen is not being updated. But keep in mind, that 800.000 lines and 100 sheets is a lot and it will take "some" time...

Comment: Just to add to this, it looks like you only need the sheet to calculate when when you copy the result back. You could use `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual' at the start of your code, force a calculate with `Application.Calculate', and switch it back on at end of code with `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic'

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in excel called "Data Table".  This feature could help you without writing VBA.  But, sorry, I cannot find the explaination in English.

Answer (score 0):

so I took the suggestion of the Arrays, but I am missing something. Here is how I tweaked the VBA code, put no values are being inserted anywhere?

```
 Sub Calculate_Sheet()

Dim orderSh As Worksheet
Dim wiroSh As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, r As Long
Dim pctComp As Double
Dim Arr1 As Variant
Dim Arr2 As Variant

With ThisWorkbook

'calculator
  Set orderSh = .Sheets("ORDER")

'price list
  Set wiroSh = .Sheets("WiroA3C100gsmI100gsm20-22pp ")

 End With

 Arr1 = wiroSh.Range("C1:M800001")
 Arr2 = orderSh.Range("F4:F14")

lastRow = wiroSh.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For r = 2 To lastRow

'display the row and percentage each 1000 rows
  If r Mod 1 = 0 Then
     Application.StatusBar = "Row = " & r & Format(r / lastRow, " #0.00%")
  End If

'copy from price list to calculator
  Arr2(1, 1) = Arr1(r, 1)
  Arr2(2, 1) = Arr1(r, 2)
  Arr2(3, 1) = Arr1(r, 3)
  Arr2(4, 1) = Arr1(r, 4)
  Arr2(5, 1) = Arr1(r, 5)
  Arr2(6, 1) = Arr1(r, 6)
  Arr2(7, 1) = Arr1(r, 7)
  Arr2(8, 1) = Arr1(r, 8)
  Arr2(9, 1) = Arr1(r, 9)
  Arr2(10, 1) = Arr1(r, 10)

'copy result
  Arr1(r, 11) = Arr2(11, 1)

Next r


 End Sub
```